# Ionic 2 Menu doesn't work when navigating pages

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I’ve set up a menu in my app.html :

```
 <ion-menu persistent="true"  id='menu' side="left" type='reveal' 
    [content]="mycontent">
   <ion-content>
     some menu content
   </ion-content>
 </ion-menu>
 <ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

and in each page, I have a button in the navbar that opens the menu :

.html

```
<ion-navbar hideBackButton>
  <button ion-button small (click)="openMenu()">
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-navbar>
```

.ts

```
openMenu(){
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true, 'menu');
    this.menuCtrl.open('menu');
}
```

The first page that has the menu button is my home.html. The menu works perfectly fine the first time this page is visited. When I navigate to the next page, the menu works fine there as well with the menu button. But when I navigate one more page ( 2 navigations from the home page ), the menu button stops working and the menu doesn’t open. And when I navigate from this page to the home page, the menu stops working there as well, and basically stops working in all pages.

It seems like making 2 navigations from the home page causes the menu to somehow disable itself for good. What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?